# Unpack daily lists from r function

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to unpack list of objects from *r* functio results as follows:

```
Unpack_daily_lists <- function (daily_lists) {

my_names <- c("a","b","c")
for (i in 1:length(daily_lists)) { 
return(assign(my_names[i], daily_lists[[i]]))
}}
```

But it doesn't work.. 
Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: You may need to change the `assign` statement with `envir = .GlobalEnv` i.e. `assign(my_names[i], daily_lists[[i]], envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: Paste to us your error message and maybe the str of the object that fills the daily_lists argument